# android : getting installed application's default methods

Tags: java, android

Is there any default methods to perform backup process. Tell me if anyone knows. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite confusing. If you are asking backup of the app then try [this - BackupRestore](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/index.html).

Comment: i tried this, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [BackupAgent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgent.html)

> Provides the central interface between an application and Android's
>   data backup infrastructure. An application that wishes to participate
>   in the backup and restore mechanism will declare a subclass of
>   BackupAgent, implement the onBackup() and onRestore() methods, and
>   provide the name of its backup agent class in its AndroidManifest.xml
>   file via the  tag's android:backupAgent attribute.

**Basic Operation**

> When the application makes changes to data that it wishes to keep
>   backed up, it should call the BackupManager.dataChanged() method. This
>   notifies the Android Backup Manager that the application needs an
>   opportunity to update its backup image. The Backup Manager, in turn,
>   schedules a backup pass to be performed at an opportune time.

Comment: if you have any example for that, tell me